# HighCharts Hide specific context Menu items

Tags: highcharts

I would like to hide specific menu items from the HighCharts context menu. Can someone point me to an example of how to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems` - this is a property in which you define items for the exporting menu.
`Highcharts.defaultOptions.buttons.contextButtons.menuItems` is an array with predefined menu items, so you copy and modify it.

```
exporting: {
        buttons: {
            contextButton: {
                menuItems: Highcharts.defaultOptions.exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.slice(4,5)
            }
        }
    }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/ta9mtap1/

See [API Docs - Menu Items](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems).